# 2 Images display at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I am using JSSOR SLIDER in my page and it works but not properly.

When the first image is displayed, some portion of the second image is also shown. How to remove that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
      var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
   });
</script>

<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative;top: 0;left: 0;height: 400px;">
 <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;position: absolute;overflow: hidden;left: 0;top: 0;height: 300px;">
  <div><img u="image" src="images/home1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img u="image" src="images/home2.jpg"></div>
  <div><img u="image" src="images/home3.jpg"></div>
  <div><img u="image" src="images/home4.jpg"></div>        
 </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me, that 2 images are not shown at the same time.

![From the Image you can see that in the right side the second image 'Home2' is seen. I want to remove that. When 2nd image will come, in the right side, the 3rd image will be seen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kRhD.png)

From the Image you can see that in the right side the second image 'Home2' is seen. I want to remove that. When 2nd image will come, in the right side, the 3rd image will be seen.

Comment: include screenshot, so we have better idea? whats going wrong and where?

Comment: can you explain what `u="image"` in youre `<img>` tag does?

Comment: @Piyush screenshot added

Comment: include the width: 400px; under style on both your div (div id="slider1_container", div u="slides").  set width size based on your images size

Comment: make height same for both div, right now it 400 and 300, make them same

Comment: That also makes no difference

Comment: Not sure what's the problem at the moment. But 'width' should be always spepcified for 'slider1_container' and 'slides' container.

Comment: I specified it, then also I get the same thing

Comment: Can you show us the full webpage this is happening on, rather then just a code snippit?

Comment: **@user1989** you can increase the width of image and use  it will solve your problem....

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the width in both divs -> slider_1_container and slides

Do you have your images perhaps different widths? 
And add in the slider1_container overflow:hidden